# How can I get Text To Speech to read a foreign language?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

When I check which languages are available Thai (th)is available  butit doesn't read the text

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void speak() {
    if(tts!=null && tts.isSpeaking()){
        tts.stop();
    }else{
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("th"));       //tts.getAvailableLanguages().;
        tts.setSpeechRate(0.7f);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    tts.speak("ซึ่งมีระยะทางส่วนใหญ่เป็น ทางหลวงแผ่นดินหมายเลข (สายบางนา - หาดเล็ก) เป็นเส้นทางคมนาคมหลักเส้นหนึ่งของประเทศไทย ", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

}
```

Comment: when you put en its working or...

Comment: @BilalUsean when i change to text to english it works

Comment: Thai, Thailand (th_TH) -> try this **tts.setLanguage(Locale.th_TH);**

Comment: Do you have the thai language TTS packages downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your code like this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void speak() {
    if(tts!=null && tts.isSpeaking()) {
        tts.stop();
    }else{
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }
}

@Override public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int res = tts.setLanguage("th_TH");
        //tts.getAvailableLanguages().;
        tts.setSpeechRate(0.7f);

        if (res >= TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
            tts.speak("ซึ่งมีระยะทางส่วนใหญ่เป็น ทางหลวงแผ่นดินหมายเลข (สายบางนา - หาดเล็ก) เป็นเส้นทางคมนาคมหลักเส้นหนึ่งของประเทศไทย ", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Because `TextToSpeech` instance is created asynchronously, so you can hear synthesis result when you control your tts after `onInit()` method was done.

Comment: Thanks for that it worked. the only change I had to make is this line    `int res = tts.setLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("th"));`